# Sending mail with hotmail smtp in php

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am trying to send email through PHPMailer. And while sending it gives me error as
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) SMTP connect() failed. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.

I really can't figure it out what's wrong. Is it the server configuration problem or code configuration problem. If anyone knows the answer please let me know.

Code below:

```
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
include('class.smtp.php');
$mail             = new PHPMailer(); //Initialize a new PHPMailer object;
$body            = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body); //Replace unwanted characters of the content
$mail->CharSet ="ISO-8859-1";
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                

$mail->From = 'email';
$mail->FromName = 'name';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.live.com';     
$mail->Port       = '465';                  
$mail->Username   = 'email ';  
$mail->Password   = 'password';           
$mail->SetFrom('email', 'who');
$mail->AddReplyTo('email','who');
$mail->Subject    = $subject;
$mail->AltBody    = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; 
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$address = $to;
$mail->AddAddress($address, '');

if(!$mail->Send()) {

    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
   echo "Message sent successfully!";
}
```

Comment: If you are testing this in your local, is the SMTP enabled and configured in your local machine (or in the server if you test it on a separate server)?

Comment: Sidenote: [`eregi_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eregi-replace.php) --- This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged. If it works for you now, good. Otherwise use [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace). To test, `echo $body;` right before `$mail->CharSet ="ISO-8859-1";`

Comment: hello everyone thanks for your reply. I have changed func to preg_replace() and now its displaying error "Message body empty". Though message body isn't empty, any idea??

Comment: Is it a server problem??. Should I report to web hosting??